# Не работает Jquery после подгрузки на AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Есть у меня скрипт чтобы при прокрутке до нужного места подгружаю часть сайта.

Но после подгрузки,не работает Jquery.

Можете мне помощь с проблемой?

```
 <script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var action = 'inactive'; 
        function load_country_data(){
        $.ajax({
           url:'test.php',
           method:"POST",
           data:{action},
           cache:false,
           dataType: "script",
           success:function(data){
            <?php if ($_GET['page'] !="2") { ?>
              $('#load_data').append(data);
              eval(data);
             <?php } ?>
               return false;
              if(data == ''){
                  $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>No Data Found</button>");
                  action = 'active';
              } else {
                  $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>Please Wait....</button>");
                  action = 'inactive';
              }
              return false;
            }
          });

       }
       $(window).scroll(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive')
        {

            setTimeout(function(){
                load_country_data();
            }, 1000);
        }
       });
    });
    </script>
```

```
<div id="load_data_message"></div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
```

Comment: Пробовали без JQuery? document.getElementById(id)

Comment: Ты хоть проверял консоль?

Comment: Просто после подгрузки блоков,на них не добавляются события от Jquery